# How does the compiler know to carry on after the whitespace in this code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string previous;
    string current;

    while (cin>>current)
    {
         if(current == previous)
         {
              cout<< "repeated word: " << previous;
         }
         previous=current;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

So I enter a sentence "blah blah foo bar" but it stops after blah, the if is not met and previous is set equal to current. Why does that not just stop it in its tracks with two variables = to blah? how does it know to analyze the next word after the white space?

Answer (score 3):

Your question was hard to understand, but I think I know why you are confused. Your confusion comes from the fact that the code is not properly indented. You assume that `return 0;` is part of the while loop, while actually, it is not. Properly indented:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  string previous;
  string current;

  while (cin >> current)
  {
    if(current == previous)
    {
      cout<< "repeated word: " << previous;
    }
    previous=current;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

this makes it clear why the while does not stop.

**Edit**: you should read an introduction to C++ streams like [this one](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-iostreams.html). (I don't know if it is any good, but it should help you).

In short, if you read into a variable from a standard stream, it parses everything until the first whitespace. If it succeeds, the stream evaluates as `true`. On the next read, it discards all the whitespace and then reads up until the next whitespace again. When there is nothing more to read, the stream will evaluate as `false`, thus terminating the loop.

Comment: I think what I dont understand is the mechanics of the while(cin>>current) and how that reads a sentence. Does it continue through white space?

Comment: @ThePeskyWabbit If you read into a variable from a stream, it reads everything into the variable up until the first found whitespace. It then discards all the whitespace and starts reading at the next non-whitespace symbol.

Answer (score 0):

`operator>>` first discards leading whitespace charaters. It then starts reading the input until either an error occurs or it encounters another whitespace character. The result is stored in the right hand operand if the read was succesful. The reference to the left hand operand is returned.

Because `cin >> current` is used in a while loop's condition, it needs to be converted to `bool`. This is done via stream's `operator bool` function. If there are any error flags set in the stream, it evaluates to `false`, otherwise to `true`.

An example, to illustrate (`-` means discard, `^` means read, `*` means stop):

```
                 "    foo    foo   bar   "
1. iteration     -----^^^*
2. iteration             ----^^^*
3. iteration                    ---^^^*
4. iteration                          ---* no input left, loop breaks
```

If you wanted to stop looping when first duplicate is encountered, you need to do that explicitly (How to do that is left as an exercise).